# Why can the sine wave become square wave by adding a inductor?

Tags: inductor

[image]

The key to let the sine wave become a square wave is to add a inductor,Why can the sine wave become square wave just by adding a inductor?

link:https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319034971_Real-world_Evaluation_of_a_Self-startup_SSHI_Rectifier_for_Piezoelectric_Vibration_Energy_Harvesting/figures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't the inductor that made that square wave. It is the switches on either side of the inductor that did so.

Comment: so if i replace inductor with mos or capacitor,the wave will be square too?

Comment: Simulate it and find out.